# Adicionar linha horizontal num DBChart para uma valor definido do eixo Y

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, gráfico, dataset

Tenho um gráfico `DBChart` com uma série com valores `float` no eixo `y` e datetime no `x`. Queria adicionar uma linha horizontal de acordo com um valor definido do eixo `y`. O `DBChart` possui a função de adicionar estas linhas com valores máximos e mínimos, porém os valores para linha no meu caso virão de outro `dataset`.

Existe uma forma simples de fazer isso? O que eu faço atualmente é adicionar sempre dois pontos para criar uma linha horizontal.